# How to output debug information to Visual Studio debugger window?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to output debug information to the debugger window of Visual Studio 2010 (not to the gui interface)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `qCritical` or `qDebug`. Under windows, they will both send information to the debugger.